# Proportions in the Android´s images

Tags: android, image

The first problem is the proportions in the images. Someone can tell me concordance between dip and pixel? Thanks!

Comment: [Here is a similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android).

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't ask questions like this before checking for similar ones. It takes you 10 secs to google this btw.

"Density-independent pixel (dp):

A virtual pixel unit that applications can use in defining their UI, to express layout dimensions or position in a density-independent way.

The density-independent pixel is equivalent to one physical pixel on a 160 dpi screen, the baseline density assumed by the platform (as described later in this document). At run time, the platform transparently handles any scaling of the dp units needed, based on the actual density of the screen in use. The conversion of dp units to screen pixels is simple: pixels = dps * (density / 160). For example, on 240 dpi screen, 1 dp would equal 1.5 physical pixels. Using dp units to define your application's UI is highly recommended, as a way of ensuring proper display of your UI on different screens."